# Where does an API call resides in a repository pattern laravel application?

Tags: php, api, laravel, laravel-5, repository-pattern

I am building a web application which has 3 rd party api integrations which include

1. Payment gateways
2. Sms vendors
3. Email providers like mandrill

Now I can have concrete repository classes where functions which talk to my DB resides. As far as I know the repositories are on standard practice used to talk to databases. Now where do I build the logic of calling a 3rd party API resides? Is that what a service provider is meant for? If then can some one show me very basic example of how the whole flow works? For eg sending an sms from a controller by calling the service provider. The question might seems dump but I am not able to get any examples or flow searching it online. There is no real world examples to be seen.

Please give some reference or example if someone has done the same.

TIA!

Comment: there are several tutorials regarding [laravel repository pattern](https://bosnadev.com/2015/03/07/using-repository-pattern-in-laravel-5/). most of them suggest using *custom php code in some namespace* and interface classes. And to note, laravel had [mandrill support](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/mail). ps. first google result on [laravel sms](https://github.com/SimpleSoftwareIO/simple-sms), also, i found on [packagist](http://packalyst.com/packages/tag/sms). just dig a little deeper, if you stuck ask people in sof.

Comment: Hi @Tezla the tutorials only are limited to accessing database and data inside the web app itself. Nothing regarding how to structure an external API is mentioned. Codeigniter had libraries where we could do all external api integration. But in larave which is the standard way of doing it? Thats not there in tutorials

Comment: because **i view repository pattern as a set of namespace with contracts (interface classes) that can do anything** - yes anything, examples might be some database access but nothing can stop you for doing something else. programming is about creativity after all. and also, try the packagist url, you might find packages that you need. and i hope nobody start CI-Laravel holy wars.

Comment: @Tezla Ya true, but its better to stick to a standard practice. If you have any sample approach for this in your mind can you please write it up as an answer?

Comment: http://laravel.io/forum/03-10-2015-how-to-make-http-request-to-external-service-in-laravel5 explains how to expose  guzzle in the controller and gives suggestions to look how Laravel uses guzzle internally for Mandril and Mailgun. Put the code for each in a service class or make it easier to separate external api logic and mail / payment gateways via repository pattern

Answer (score 1):

Repositories are, in the strict sense, for encapsulating methods for advanced access to a set of data.

That being said, there is nothing that says this is the only way to use them. The pattern itself allows for you to group different processes into different places, improving the organization of your code.

At this point one could argue they are no longer repositories, but the most important factor isn't just adhering to design patterns in the strictest of senses. It's using the pattern that suits your applications needs, and sometimes that may also come with distorting the meaning of what that pattern implies.

Not every standard or pattern will perfectly fit into your application, nor should it. You should make changes where needed and break convention when appropriate. This is a matter of judgement. If you think it's simpler to use Repositories as effectively collections of advanced access methods (with application logic in another layer like Services), or collections of application logic. Even both.